# send <form> information through 2 different Submit buttons, that calls the same function but need to know from which submit button came the call

Tags: javascript, forms, function, button, submit

I'm sending  information through 2 different Submit buttons, that calls the same function but I need to know from which submit button came the call.

I have a form with 'x' parameters that I'm going to send to a js function thats going to validate the data. After I validate the data I need to send that data to diferent js function depending on the submit button press

my form is like this:

```
<form name="Datos_ConfiguracionRangos_Tension_Laboral" action="#" onsubmit="Consultar_ConfiguracionRangos('Tension', 'Laboral'); return false" method="post">
    <button id="button" type="submit" name="graficar" value ="graficar">Graficar</button>   
    <button id="button2" type="submit" name="guardar" value ="guardar"> Guardar Configuraciones</button>    
</form>`
```

Comment: Maybe it's worth you read the accepted answer to thi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to allow your script to submit the form, and use regular buttons.

```
<button id="button" onclick="validateMe(this)" value ="graficar">Graficar</button>
```

...then in your function:

```
function validateMe(e) {
     alert(e.value) <-- this tells you which button was presssed.
     .... your validation code ...
     document.forms.Datos_ConfiguracionRangos_Tension_Laboral.submit();
}
```

Comment: thanks!! that work. Basically knowing which button was pressed I can modified to do what I need to do